# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 in redux

Tags: json, local-storage, token, jsonparser

I'm creating a user register and I'm using the redux toolkit. When the user details are not in the local storage I'm setting it to null. But since the beginning the user is undefined, it should assign it a null value but I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

due to this code:

```
// Get user from localStorage
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

//initials state
const initialState = {
  user: user ? user : null,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
};
```

How should I write it or what I'm doing wrong? I understand the value undefined is what is being stringified.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you see `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`, it's almost certainly because you're trying to pass `undefined` to `JSON.parse`. JS will automatically convert it to the string `"undefined"`, which is not valid JSON.

Something like `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user") || "null")` should do the trick. This will pass the string `"null"` (which is valid JSON) instead if `localStorage.getItem("user")` returns anything "falsy".

This also means you don't need the `user ? user : null` later on - you can replace that with just `user`.

Comment: I'm still getting the error even after replacing the way you've mentioned

Comment: Hmm, is it possible that you have actually stored the string `"undefined"` in local storage at some point? If so, clearing out your local storage should fix it, or you could edit it manually in devtools. (Assuming the code that caused it to be stored like that is now fixed.)

Comment: Thank you David I think I should start developing on Guest accounts

Comment: Thank you very clear explanation in a minute. Not need tons of text reading or watch hours of video :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearing local storage solved the issue.Thank you